# Foundation 6 core js error

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am using a brand new install of Foundation 6 and trying to set up a closable toggle box (http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/toggler.html).

For some reason I am getting this error though..

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_init' of undefined`

on line 245 of foundation.core.js.

This is the HTML on my page, straight from the closable example in the Foundation docs..

```
<div class="callout" data-closable>
  <button class="close-button" data-close>&times;</button>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore praesentium sint alias dolorum qui vel quaerat, libero consequatur non esse asperiores veritatis commodi, odit eum ipsam nemo dicta iste aliquam.</p>
</div>
```

This is the javascript I have at the bottom of my HTML before the `</body>`.

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.toggler.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here or what I'm missing. Everything works if I load the entire Foundation javascript library but that's complete overkill for what I need.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error with multiple plugins from Foundation 6. After doing some searching and reading, it turned out that `foundation.core` has a co-dependency with `foundation.util.mediaQuery`.

Try inserting `foundation.util.mediaQuery` after `foundation.core`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not working for you because you do not have motion ui js or css. Include and try, I think you'll be happy.

It is actually foundation.util.motion.js that you are missing but that alone won't fix it you need the motion ui css file as well.

Comment: Link only answers are not helpful.  Please provide the relevant information so that future users can understand why what you are saying will help them. :)

Comment: What? I just tested this it's not working for him because of motion ui, thats all...see I helped him.

Comment: What at that link answers the question?  Put that into your answer here so that it's useful two years from now when that link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after trying to solve it using npm (frustrated) I simply imported JQuery on my HTML.

Go on this link and copy the google CDN

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

and paste it on your html before you import the foundation scripts. I hope it helps someone who is still having this issue. 
Cheers!